# Sort the List of Github Repositories

Tags: git, sorting, github, automation, graphql

I am new to GitHub API, not sure if it's the best solution either.

But suppose I have a list of Repositories in which I want to commit in the future or have committed already as a `.md` file, can be a `.txt` file also if it suits the purpose.

e.g.

```
| Serial Number  | Name |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| 1  | [Badges](https://github.com/badges/shields)  |
| 2  | [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow)  |
etc
```

Now let's say, I contributed once in TF.
I want to sort the `.md` file or `.txt` according to the number of contributions.

Of course, the list might contain REPO in which I haven't contributed at all like Badges here.

Lastly, can someone suggest how to automate this, I think GitHub Action is the best course possible.

EDIT - 1

Explanation - The `.md` file or `.txt` file (which is more suitable as pointed out in comments) will contain a list of repositories, I want to contribute to in the future. I want my script, to automatically sort the list, according to a number of contributions I make to keep a track of them.

EDIT - 2

I know the basics of GitHub GrraphQl API.

Using this query I can generate a number of repositories i have contributed to -

```
{
  viewer {
    repositoriesContributedTo(first: 100, contributionTypes: [COMMIT, ISSUE, PULL_REQUEST, REPOSITORY]) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner

      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because your question seems a bit unclear. Am I correct that you want to read the file and just sort the lines by the number of contributions you made to the repository? Markdown is not ideal for parsing, it would be easier with a text file with just the links. You basically need to find the owner/repo name and get the number of contributions from the GitHub API. You then need to regenerate the file.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, I just want to sort the list of Repo according to contributions and if possible automate this thing. And i got your point, i will edit the question right away

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and what is the problem with it? Which step are you stuck on, for example: reading the list; extracting the data for a repo from it; getting the contribution data for that repo; sorting the list using that data; updating the file with the new order; ...?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Edited the question accordingly